# Problemas al cerrar desplegable haciendo click

Tags: jquery

el primer título muestre y oculte los otros tres. clic primer título y muestren los otros tres.... primer título desaparecio. help ayudame.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".menu_item:nth-child(2)").hide();
 $(".menu_item:nth-child(3)").hide();
 $(".menu_item:nth-child(4)").hide();

 $('.menu_item').click(function() { 
  $(".menu_item").slideToggle();
 });
 
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">

  <div class="menu_item">
    <h3><a href="#"> Sesión demo 1</a></h3> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu_item">
    <h3><a href="#"> Sesión demo 2</a></h3> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu_item">
    <h3><a href="#"> Sesión demo 3</a></h3> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu_item">
    <h3><a href="#"> Sesión demo 4</a></h3> 
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Escribe tranquilo, calmado y en español hermano, no se entiende nada tu pregunta.

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver si gracias y mal lenguaje nativo.

Comment: Describe cómo quieres que se comporte el listado. Quieres que cada elemento sólo haga slideToggle de sí mismo?

Comment: Compañero, hablas correcto castellano? Lo digo por que no se entiende nada de tu problema ❤

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: en segunda instancia, entendí que el primer título muestra u oculta a los otros tres cada vez que se le hace click.

En un inicio, los items 2,3 y 4 deben estar ocultos.

Lo que debieras hacer es asignar el handler del evento `click` solamente al primer elemento. Y dentro de él, ejecutar `slideToggle` sólo en los otros tres:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".menu_item:nth-child(2)").hide();
 $(".menu_item:nth-child(3)").hide();
 $(".menu_item:nth-child(4)").hide();

 $(".menu_item:nth-child(1)").click(function() { 
    $(".menu_item:nth-child(2)").slideToggle();
    $(".menu_item:nth-child(3)").slideToggle();
    $(".menu_item:nth-child(4)").slideToggle();
 });
 
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">

  <div class="menu_item">
    <h3><a href="#"> Sesión demo 1</a></h3> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu_item">
    <h3><a href="#"> Sesión demo 2</a></h3> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu_item">
    <h3><a href="#"> Sesión demo 3</a></h3>
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu_item">
    <h3><a href="#"> Sesión demo 4</a></h3> 
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: pero quiero hacer que cada título 1 muestre u oculte sus titulos 2 ,3 ,4

Comment: Y los títulos 2, 3 y 4 son "hijos" del título 1?

Comment: Reformulo mi pregunta: quieres que pinchar el primer título muestre y oculte los otros tres. Pero ¿Que debe ocurrir cuando pinchas en uno de esos 3? Supongo que esos no deben mostrar ni ocultar nada.

Comment: si primer titulo muestre y oculta los otros tres , como muestra u oculta un elemento con efecto de deslizamiento (acordeón).

Comment: Edité mi respuesta, ve si te sirve

Comment: si super gracias.

Comment: @amenadiel puedes reducir bastante el código, en la primera parte donde ocultas los elementos puedes usar `$(".menu item:not(:first-child)").hide();` y adentro del event listener puedes usar `$(this).siblings().slideToggle();`. De esa manera además no tienes que agregar un selector por cada elemento nuevo que agregues a la lista.

Comment: es cierto, y más eficiente aún sería darle una clase extra a los submenus toggleables, pero quise intervenir lo menos posible su código para que le fuera evidente qué había cambiado.